# Converting a PostgresSQL query into Knex.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have to use the `LOWER` function in `whereIn` using knex.
I want to change the below line of code

```
whereIn("name", members);
```

If I do `whereIn('LOWER("name")', members);`, getting error as
`Column LOWER("name") is not present.`
I tried to use knex.raw but again not getting the correct syntax.

```
const roleMembers = await t("roles")
          .select({ role_id: "id" }, "name")
          .whereIn(t.raw("LOWER('name')"), members);
```

Error: [image]

[index.d.ts(1184, 5)](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/types/index.d.ts#L1185)

When I try to add await, syntax error goes away but when I execute this code I get the below error

error: `LOWER(name) - syntax error at or near "LOWER"`
I'm referring http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereIn

We have `whereRaw`, Do we have a similar thing for `whereIn`? Need some help to fix this issue.

**Note: I used all LOWER, lower, Lower.**

Comment: What if you do `whereIn("lower(name)", members);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is below.

```
const roleMembers = await t("roles")
          .select({ role_id: "id" }, "name")
          .whereIn(t.raw('LOWER("name")') as any, members);
```

My changes to the original code are

1. Quotes:  swapped " and  '
2. lower, Lower and LOWER worked
3. Typescript error: added as any

Thanks Matt and Mikael for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

`knex.raw()` can be used for the column component

```
knex('members').whereIn(knex.raw('Lower("name")'), members)
```

```
select * from `members` where Lower("name") in ('Tom', 'Dick', 'harry')
```

Comment: Matt, I tried your code but still getting error. I have updated my question.

Comment: not sure.. works for me with your extended query as well.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar You did the `t.raw` wrong. Type of the quotes do matter. `knex.raw('Lower("name")')` is not the same that `knex.raw("Lower('name')")`

Comment: Thanks, Mikael I didn't notice "quote". It really matters.